# LIKE mysql chr /-1

Tags: mysql, ascii, where-clause, sql-like

my research,

admit a WHERE (SUBSTRING_INDEX (`destination`, '-', 1)) LIKE 'A%'

I appreciate get list more or less, let me explain;

the condition "WHERE for like 'a%'" show me the destinations starting with A, but I also want to retrieve the Z and B because Z

Another example, "WHERE (SUBSTRING_INDEX (`destination`, '-', 1)) LIKE 'F%'", result first letter F in supplement: E and G

Comment: Nope, I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   destination >= CHAR(ORD('F') - 1)
        AND destination < CHAR(ORD('F') + 2)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56aef/2)

Comment: @ hjpotter92 sniff @ Quassnoi great ;) but dont have Z for A, for the moment, it's cool ! thank you !!